# Array muy simple en C (microcontroladores PIC)

Tags: array, c, matriz, pic, microcontrolador

Tengo este `array` para el código en un microcontrolador:

```
char const textos_simples[20][16] = {"INICIANDO","SISTEMA","COLOQUE BILLETE ","Y PRESIONE A    ","NO SE RECONOCIO ","BILLETE","PARA RETIRAR","INGRESE LA CLAVE","RETIRO","ACEPTADO","PRESIONE A PARA","CERRAR LA CAJA","AUDIO ENCENDIDO","AUDIO APAGADO","CONFIRME LA","NUEVA CLAVE","LA CLAVE SE","HA CAMBIADO"};
```

Quiero imprimir una variable en un LCD

```
   lcd_clear(); // limpia la LCD
   lcd_gotoxy(1,1); // posicion (x,y)
```

Aquí viene lo raro. Si escribo 16 de frente, me imprime el valor asignado a la casilla 16.

```
// FUNCIONA ASI: lcd_putc("texto a imprimir en LCD 16x2")

lcd_putc(textos_simples[16]);
// devuelve "LA CLAVE SE" que es el valor numero 16
```

Pero si lo hago desde una variable, me imprime "INICIANDO" que es la casilla 0.

```
unsigned int kk = 16;
lcd_gotoxy(1,2);
lcd_putc(textos_simples[kk]);
```

Comment: ¿Tu array tiene 20 filas y 16 columnas? Además, si hacés `lcd_gotoxy(1,1);` y luego `lcd_putc(textos_simples[kk]);`, ¿qué te imprime?